# Load SHORT country names

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, countries

I need to change the name value from

```
lib/Zend/Locale/Data/de.xml
```

I have there two lines:

```
    <territory type="HK">Sonderverwaltungszone Hongkong</territory>
    <territory type="HK" alt="short">Hongkong</territory>
```

Magento is loading the first line while I'd need the second one. As there is the `alt="short"` I think I miss some setting somewhere. 
How to adjust that **update save** (not changing the given file)